# How to return an enemy to original position after losing aggro [issues[

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I have an enemy that, once you get close enough, will chase you around and try to attack you. Once you get far enough away, it will run back to where it was originally.

The issue I'm having is that once it runs back to where its starting point is, but doesn't quite hit the point, and keeps falling over and trying to get to that exact point..

Here's what I have for code for that section:

```
if (inAggroRange()) {
        //In aggro range
            if (!inAttackRange()) {
                chase();
            } else {
                animation.CrossFade(animationAttack.name);
                attack();

                if (animation[animationAttack.name].time > 0.9 * animation[animationAttack.name].length) {
                    impacted = false;
                }
            }
        } else if (!inAggroRange()){
            //Go back to home position
            if (!(transform.position == enemyHomePosition)) {
                animation.CrossFade(animationRun.name);
                transform.LookAt(enemyHomePosition);
                controller.SimpleMove(transform.forward * speed);
            } else {
            //Enemy is at home position
                animation.CrossFade(animationIdle.name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: not sure why this is getting downvoted. i mean its not pretty, but i think its legit ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
private readonly float maxDistanceToHomePosition = 0.3f; // change this value as you like

...

if((transform.position - enemyHomePosition).magnitude > maxDistanceToHomePosition)
{
    ...
} 

...
```

the way you are doing it, the enemy is trying to reach one specific point but without a megaton of luck it will always be just a bit over, then turn around and try again. Much like a golf player trying to hit the whole but alyways hitting to hard.

edit: also think about using != for 'not equal', in my opinion thats a bit easier to read

Comment: Okay... where do I put this?
I tried putting it where my current if statement is, and that just made him stop when I got too far away, he didn't run back to where he was. I updated my question to include the full statement

Comment: i fixed the code, it should work now. Do you understand what it does?

Comment: Should probably go around the "(!(transform.position == enemyHomePosition)) " section, close to the end. You might also need to adjust the float up/down

Comment: no its meant to be there instead :) i just changed the behaviour from "stop when at the exact homeposition" to "stop when you are really close to your home position"(think home position is (0,0) if the enemy is at (0.00001, 0.00056) he should stop moving). The error i made was that i wrote '<' instead of '>' in my first post.